# Cycling communities organized rides in Leipzig , Germany

Tags: germany, group-rides, organized-rides

in my country Dudes usually gather and make some Cycling groups , they usually organize rides during weekends periodically.

i'm planning to spend some time in Leipzig, Germany this summer and i know Germany has a lot of places which would be wonderful to cycle through.

i'm asking if i can find cycling groups that organize such things or trips using bicycles in Germany.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the website of the ADFC bicycle club in Leipzig http://www.adfc-leipzig.de. The "Termine" link has a list of their events including bike rides.  Also the "Radtouren"link might be of interest to you.  Of course everything is in the German language.